# Using plot() to make basic animations

Tags: r, animation, plot

You can use the plot function in R repeatedly to make basic animations. Example:

```
x <- seq(0, 0.99, by=0.01)
y <- 4*x*(1 - x)
x <- seq(0, 4.99, by=0.01)
y <- rep(y, 5)
y <- y*exp(-0.05*x)

# animate
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  plot(x[i], y[i], xlim=c(0, 5), ylim=c(0, 1))
}
```

However, if you try to add lines or other features or multiple plots, the lines flicker at best or do not show up during animation at worst. (At least in Rgui. I haven't tested this in Rstudio)

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  plot(x[i], y[i], xlim=c(0, 5), ylim=c(0, 1))
  lines(x[1:i], y[1:i], col=2)
}

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
  plot(x[i], y[i], xlim=c(0, 5), ylim=c(0, 1))
  plot(x[i], y[i], xlim=c(0, 5), ylim=c(0, 1), pch=20)
}
```

The plot seems to be refreshed only at the end of each loop, so adding a delay through Sys.sleep() doesn't work.  I guess what I'm after is the plot equivalent of `flush.console()`.

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  plot(x[i], y[i], xlim=c(0, 5), ylim=c(0, 1))
  lines(x[:1:i], y[1:i], col=2)
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
```

I know it is possible to achieve this sort of thing through ggplot, but I was hoping for a non-ggplot answer because I understand R's base plotting functionalities well, whereas ggplot is still a mystery to me.

**If the animation looks completely fine to you**

You might have a better computer than me. Try this code instead:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  Sys.sleep(0.02)
  plot(x[i], y[i], xlim=c(0, 5), ylim=c(0, 1))
  Sys.sleep(0.02)
  lines(x[1:i], y[1:i], col=2)
}
```

Comment: works fine for me, depends more on the device you are using, try `x11()` and the rstudio works well too. the "correct" way to do this is to write each image to a file and combine into a gif or mp4

Comment: @rawr `x11()` just creates a new window on top of the old - and will keep going until you've run out of windows at 63. I have used gifs in the past, but it's not particularly relevant to what I'm using it for here. I'm wanting to observe the preliminary outputs of a calculation while it's running, rather than spend time at the end building a gif.

Comment: then youre not using it correctly, `x11` is only called once

Comment: @rawr x11() is called anyway when you use plot() and there's no plot window already open. How you're using x11() is functionally identical to *not* using it.

Comment: not at all true, it depends on your options, system, and (lack of) IDE in use. i don't understand why you're arguing with me about this, i tried your example in the command line, r gui, rstudio, i tried with the rstudio device, quartz, x11. and you're over there calling x11 for every plot reaching the active window limit. you have 200 rep, don't you think i have the slightest idea of what i'm talking about?

Comment: @rawr No I'm not. Do you see any x11() in my original post? Give me your code, however you're using x11(), and I'll tell you if it works or not.

Comment: `x11() just creates a new window on top of the old - and will keep going until you've run out of windows at 63` you literally are. you put it inside the loop or something.

Comment: @rawr I am literally not. look at my code again. Please look at my code again. Please stop treating this like a 'battle' to be 'won'. I am **not** using x11() in my original code. I tried it at your suggestion even though it made no sense to. Both inside and outside the loop It didn't work.

Comment: you denied what I said then you admit it "Both inside and outside the loop" have a nice day

Comment: your personality could use some humility

Comment: @I'm being serious. You turned a comment chain asking for clarification into an unnecessary argument. There's a lot more bothering you than just me, I can tell. Take a 20 minute break, have a walk around. It's no use getting pent up over internet randos.

Comment: I'm taking time out of my day to help you, i tried your code every which way with different programs and graphics devices. you admitted that you used x11 inside the loop, i knew that from the first time you mentioned the window limit and "a new window on top" trying to be nice when i absolutely knew you had no idea what you were doing. then you gaslight me by denying the thing you just admitted. grow up

Comment: @rawr I didn't use an `x11()` until you suggested it, and when I did, it didn't work.

Comment: i didnt say you did. i said it was another option since you werent happy with the device you were using whatever it was. then you just put it in the loop, and i said that was not correct

Comment: @rawr you are using Rstudio, not Rgui, correct?

Comment: @rawr I use Rgui - I see that Rstudio's behaviour with `x11()` is different and trying my code doesn't 'animate' at all unless a new window is generated with x11(). in Rgui calling x11() then plot() is the same as just calling plot() if there are no previous plot windows. It still leaves me at square one - the additional lines do flicker as they're plotted and with Sys.sleep() imitating a heavy computation load they don't show up at all.

Comment: rstudio has its own device `getOption('device')` will give you the default. the rstudio gd does not flicker as xquartz and x11 can do although it seems to be slower at times, x11 performs better on my machine but is not the default, so I call x11 explicitly before the loop. if there is no device open _and_ your default is x11, then there is no need to call x11 first, correct. if it is a matter of your machine, why not call the plot once and loop over the `line` only so the entire plot does not have to be refreshed